# How does the spell thievery ability work when you don't have a blank scroll or page?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e-playtest

(Pathfinder Playtest pg 172)

> #### Spell Thievery
>
> If you use Palm an Object or Steal an Object on a scroll, spellbook, or similar item, you can remove the magical writing without disturbing the parchment or other surface it was inscribed upon. **When you do, you must have a blank scroll or page in your possession that you can transfer the magical writing onto, or else the magic is expended and lost.** The GM usually applies a penalty to observers’ Perception checks and DCs to notice the theft, unless the writing is on open display (in the case of an unfurled scroll, for example). You gain a +2 circumstance bonus to your check because you don’t need to collect the entire object. However, higher-level magic is harder to steal, so the DC is increased by the spell’s level.

I want to say the magic does nothing, but it seems like it might just go off, does it actually do so?

If it does go off, what happens with single target spells? (I figure AOE spells will just be centered at the target of the ability)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The magic writings on the scroll vanishes

If you attempt to *steal* the magic on a scroll, and you have to scroll to transfer the writings to, the magic on the original scroll is simply spent, vanishes into nothing, and the owner is left with a blank scroll.

> the magic is expended and **lost**

The word *expended* is used throughout the book to mean that it is used up (with or without effect), or that it's lost without doing anything, like when the many abilities that consume a spell slot fail. They simply say that "the spell slot is expended without effect".

> Each prepared spell is expended after a single casting
>
> the spell is expended with no effect
>
> that component is expended in the casting
>
> When you lose a spell, you’ve expended the prepared spell or spell slot

The wording is used again when describing **Wands**:

> Charges: A wand is similar to a consumable item, but unlike consumables, it isn’t destroyed when first used. Instead, it has 10 charges when first crafted, one of which is **expended** each time a spell is cast from the wand. Once the charges are depleted, the wand becomes nonmagical. The number of charges in a wand you find might be determined randomly or otherwise decided by the GM.

But notice here that when a charge is consumed, it is spent to *cast a spell*, a wording that lacks completely on *Spell Thievery*.